# Weird internal server error in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-query-builder

Why I'm getting an error status code of 500 Internal Server error while the query seems to work?

Here's what I found out, when I remove the `->result();` in my query it returns status 200 which is good. But if I add `->result();` in my query it gives me the Internal Server Error.

Here is my query:

```
$this->db->select('message_tbl.id, message_tbl.message, message_tbl.date_created, message_sent.from_id, message_received.to_id, message_received.is_read');    
$this->db->from('message_tbl');
$this->db->join('message_received', 'message_received.msg_id = message_tbl.id');
$this->db->join('message_sent', 'message_sent.msg_id = message_tbl.id');
$this->db->where('message_sent.delete_status',0);
$this->db->where('message_received.delete_status',0);
$this->db->where('message_received.to_id',$this->user_id);
$this->db->where('message_received.parent_id',0);           
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: That's a signal you need to check your server logs and find out more detail. It's only "weird" because you don't have the details.

Comment: If you remove `->result`, you are not getting an result or error... that's why. Use echo `$this->db->last_query();die;`  to output the last query and check it in your phpMyAdminPanel or similar. or press F12 to check your browsers network tab TO FIND THE ERROR OF YOUR QUERY

Comment: probably the error comes from `$this->user_id`

Comment: @Vickel thanks i found it. Its a query error in my view. I tried this $this->db->last_query();die;